# Identify that part of my S56 BMW M Coupe

Tags: bmw, drivetrain

There is a driveline component with a rubber shock absorption ring in it.  It sits between the tranny and driveshaft.

I cannot remember the name of this component.

Does someone know the name of this device?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a picture of what you're looking for and what do you mean this is the 4th time writing this?

Comment: It's up underneath shielding and this car is set very low to the ground.  It would be an hour work minimum to get the shot.   Sorry man.

Comment: Is it two pieces of rubber connected by bolts? It may be designed to shear if too much torque is applied to the drive shaft or something locks up. I forget what it's called. like http://www.bmw2002faq.com/applications/core/interface/imageproxy/imageproxy.php?img=http%3A%2F%2Fi617.photobucket.com%2Falbums%2Ftt260%2F742002turbo%2FBella%2FPicture020.jpg&key=bc7a13be88fb6a813b145f439353a162741e85c1d6bde82f6d8caf165f1f814a ?

Comment: It's for energy absorption in the driveline.  All vehicles have some sort of mechanism to do this.  BMW just happens to do it here.

Comment: I don't have an expectation.  I have a hope.  Kinda passive aggressive with that.

Comment: Welcome to mechanics SE.  Where the answers come with pictures!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think most BMW owners call them a "[Giubo](http://blog.bavauto.com/14113/bmw-how-to-properly-install-driveshaft-flex-disc-giubo/)". I have no idea where that comes from or why, but you'll find it very easily by Googling it by that name.

Comment: I'm sure it's short for some fancy Germanic word with 20 syllables.  Ty.

Comment: And now that you said that it tickles my brain and reminds me that's what the crazy name was that I couldn't remember.  ;-)

Comment: Good one dude....

Answer (score 6):

Are you referring to the Driveshaft FlexDisc?

[image]

Comment: I can't vote in your answer. Sorry.

Comment: @GrindingMetal, you can accept it, though

Comment: Did that.  Thanks.  Not familiar with the features.  Appreciated.

Comment: For sure, we're here to help! Always fun to learn about new stuff too.

Comment: @GrindingMetal sure you can vote *now*.